# Series of clEnqueueWriteBuffer calls

Tags: opencl

If I call clEnqueueWriteBuffer four times in sequence, and I receive an event when the fourth
call completes, can I assume that the three previous writes have also completed?

Comment: If you haven't set the `CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE` property of the command queue, then yes.

Comment: Thanks! Re-submit this as an answer so that I can give you full marks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the queue is in-order this will work. However, for maintenance reasons it might not be wise to assume that the queue is in-order. In that case you would be better off:

- using a barrier to explicitly say that you want every preceding
  command to have completed
- chaining the copy operations with events
  between each pair
- or creating a marker based on the completion events of all of the copy operations

Better to design your code for the future rather than make assumptions based on the flags you've passed to your queue now.

Comment: I ended up waiting for completion events from all four copy calls